# What are methods of differentiating body string from headers and dates

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have some problems separating my strings from header and body. 
Example:

```
CBC NEWS
11,29,2016
Today is raining.
School starts.

NASA
12,1,2015
New planet found.
```

My objective is to make the headers (in this case, NASA and CBC NEWS) a dictionary key, the items are the date and body in a tuple.

```
{CBC NEWS : (11292016,Today is raining.)}
```

But I can't think of a way to separate the strings, so what are common ways to differentiate the header string (CBC NEWS) from body string (Today is raining)?

Comment: In this case, I would just split on blank lines (e.g. `text.split('\n\n')`) and then take the first line.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I dont quite understand

Comment: `text = file.read(); sections = text.split('\n\n')` then for each section the first line is the header.

Comment: What are the actual datatypes of the expected results? Strings should be quoted and integers can remain as-is. `{CBC NEWS : (11292016,Today is raining.)}` is not a valid dictionary